# Change view height on motion event as i swipe down or swipe up

Tags: android

As making an level view as move up view height should be increased or if move down the height should reduce ?
can any one refer me or guide me please

[image]

Comment: Please add your xml files and what you have tried.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.